# CAReportingService using up RAM

Tags: macos, memory, macos-big-sur

I have the service CAReportingService on macOS Big Sur (11.2.3).
It is running as root and taking up 7,5GB of ram.

I have tried to close it a couple of times, but it keeps coming back.

Does anyone know how I can disable or fix the problem?

[image]

To temporarily disable it I use the command 'sudo kill -9 2699', where 2699 is the PID from ActivityMonitor.

Comment: Currently running @ 167% CPU on MacOS Ventura 13.0.1.  Crazy.

Answer (score 1):

`CAReportingService` is part of `Core Audio` in Console.app.

It's reported to have high CPU usage.

**If you want to adjust the priority of it:**

```
renice -n "±20" -p PID (e.g. 2699 in your case)
```

This will `renice` or reprioritize `CAReportingService` to the minimum (+20) or the maximum (-20) *requested* priority. Note the sign might be confusing.